# My question about kubespray was closed for being a "question for network infrastructure or server professional"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, reopen-closed

1) Kubespray, ansible and kubernetes has it's community support in stackoverflow.

2) I did a question about "how to do" an action (add a kubernetes master node) and that is not right supported by kubespray
[how rebuild the masters nodes of a cluster deployed with kubespray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59241398/how-rebuild-the-masters-nodes-of-a-cluster-deployed-with-kubespray)

3) 3 users voted to close the question as off-topic, saying " about professional server or networking-related infrastructure administration"

4) with the query "kubespray master node" are different 49 questions, all open except mine, but on the same direction or sense than mine: kubespray doesn't worked right, what way take

Doesn't make sense that these editors close and marked my question as off topic while stackoverflow is the place of these 3 technologies and I asked about a fail of one and how do

Comment: Note that there being other similar questions open does not validate this one staying so. Since the site is community-moderated, the other questions could have slipped the curation radar. That search does not account for deleted questions either. And even if the subject was on-topic for the site, it is questionable whether you have included all the necessary details for other people to reproduce the problem (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: On a side note, it is misguided to link curation with rudeness like in your last comment of yours on the question. Volunteers are spending their time to create a repository of high quality questions and answers, and closing questions with issues is an important part of this site, so that comment is unwarranted.

Comment: And some random software's community deciding to move their support to SO doesn't make it magically on-topic here.

Comment: @info2000 Those three points would make separate concerns. Alas, all of them are refutable. (1) questions must be self-contained and not have important details behind links, as described in the link above: _"Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem in the question itself"_; (2) your assumption that people close questions for egotistical reasons has no foundation; (3) we already have some machine learning based tools to assist moderators and curators, but it's not enough help, and they are not sophisticated enough to be autonomous.

Answer (score 5):

The topic of your question is outside the scope of Stack Overflow. As described in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), is a Q&A site specifically for computer programming. Configuring Kubernetes clusters is not programming. The close-voters were not acting in error; the question was rightly closed.

As others have mentioned in the comments, the fact that you find similar questions is not sufficient to prove that your question is on-topic. Stack Overflow gets thousands of questions per day; it is impossible to guarantee that all off-topic questions get closed immediately. We do our best, but we’re not perfect. You can help us out: if you see an off-topic question, please flag it accordingly so that it can be reviewed.

Comment: about " Configuring Kubernetes clusters is not programming."
 the 22k questions about kubernetes in SO?
Additionally, my question is not about kubernetes, is about kubesplay-ansible and it's fail to add a master node.
this is covered in "computer programming" because "ansible" is rightly covered by SO

doesn't makes sense the reasons to mark off-topic my question

Comment: Configuring infrastructure tools isn’t programming. I already addressed that the existence of other questions is not evidence that yours is on-topic.